# Representational State Transfer (REST) in Common Lisp

Tags: rest, lisp, common-lisp

I am teaching myself Common Lisp and I'm creating a simple program that interfaces with facebook's graph api. Facebook uses REST and json.

This is a really simple question, but where are the REST libraries in Common Lisp? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to query Facebook API and process their JSON output, you probably need `Drakma` (an HTTP-client) and `cl-json` or `yason` JSON-processing libraries.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Vsevolod said. Don't forget to execute

```
(push (cons "application" "json") drakma:*text-content-types*)
```

or whatever the content-type Facebook uses or drakma will return data as byte arrays which IIRC no JSON library knows what to do with it.

And my JSON parser library of choice is [ST-JSON](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/st-json/) because it allows you to choose whether you want JS objects decoded as plists or alists.